# Display output 4 per line

Tags: c++

I'm taking my first programming course and am new to this forum. Any help will be greatly appreciated! For one of my class assignments I had to write a program that would find the factors of a given number, I've got the program up and running but one of the stipulations is that the output must be displayed four to a line and that's where I'm running into trouble. I've read around on some other forums as well as here but I guess I'm not grasping what I would have to do in my particular case.

Here's my code as is:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int n;

    while (cout << "Please enter a number: " && !(cin >> n)  || (n < 0.0) || cin.peek() != '\n')
    {
        cout << "Input must be a positive number!" << endl;    
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }

    for (int i=2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        while (n % i == 0)
        {
            n /= i;
            cout << "*" << i;
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    system ("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since its a homework, I dont want to give too much. One way you can think about is, after you `cout` 4 times, you can add a `cout << endl;`.  Now the question is, how can you know if you have printed 4 values already? TIP: How can you know if you have printed multiple of 4 values so you can add a new line?

Comment: You've got the right idea with modulo. There's really no reason to divide unless you're printing so many lines you might wrap your int, which is unlikely. The normal logic here is `n && !(n % i)` to avoid triggering on the first row.

Comment: @tadman: The modulo is here to find divisors, and the division is to print multiple factor as for `n=36` print `*2*2*3*3`.

Comment: Whatever you're doing, it's a little hard to follow. Variable names better than `n` would help.

Comment: Yeah, since my initial programs have been rather simple with very few variables, I have been prone to just naming variables letters that I can easily recall. I know that as I go further and deal with more complicated programs with more variables I will need to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to add a counter outside the loop.

```
//int counter = 0;

for (int i=2; i <= n; i++)
{
     while (n % i == 0)
    {
        n /= i;
        cout << "*" << i;
    }

}
```

The counter will need to keep track of how many entries have been printed.

```
Once you have seen 4 entries printed:  
    print an extra newline  
    and set the counter back to 0
```

Comment: Ok I was messing around with that but I was applying it inside of the loop so it wasn't working correctly! Thank you for your help. Maybe you can help me with another problem I'm having in the same program. How can I get the asterisk to begin printing after the first factor? For example if I input 12 the output is currently " *2*2*3 ". I'd like it to be " 2 * 2 * 3".

Comment: You will need to do "cout << i << " * ";" instead of "cout << " * " << i;".

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following:

```
void display_factors(std::size_t n, std::size_t factor_by_line)
{
    const char* sep = "";
    std::size_t count = 0;

    std::cout << n << " = ";
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; ++i) {
        while (n % i == 0) {
            n /= i;
            if (count == factor_by_line) {
                std::cout << std::endl;
                count = 0;
            }
            ++count;
            std::cout << sep << i;
            sep = " * ";
        }
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/eqFaAP)